# silverlight slider flow direction for vertical orientation

Tags: silverlight, xaml, slider, orientation

Is there a way to change the flow direction of the slider for the vertical orientation?  If not, is there a way to change the background color to a color without it having that weird shaded effect?  I want the bright color of the slider to be on top and the shaded portion to be on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the great responses, but I ended up solving this one on my own.  After much research, I finally discovered that I should edit the slider's template and that it can be easily done in Expression Blend.  I found a pretty good tutorial for editing templates [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Customizing-WP7-Slider-in-different-ways).  Once I started editing the template, I went to the vertical fill portion of the vertical slider and changed the transparency to 20% and changed the vertical track portion of the the vertical slider to 100%.  This is where the shaded effect comes from.  Then, I just switched the Fill properties for the vertical fill and the vertical track, so that the top part would be referenced by the slider's Foreground property and the bottom (now shaded part) would be referenced by the slider's Background property.